# How do I install the apps that I develop on liveandroid distribution

Tags: android

How do I install the android apps on [live-android](http://code.google.com/p/live-android/) distribution? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explain in the [doc](http://code.google.com/p/live-android/wiki/howtoinstallapps).